# How to reduce the time complexity while dealing with arrays? In Java

Tags: java, loops, optimization, time-complexity

A array a is given with n elements, and we need to swap the elements d number of times. The below code works fine for smaller n and d values, but when the n and d values are in the order of 10^5. The time consumed is huge. How do I optimize the code?

```
for(int i=0;i<d;i++){
        int j=0;
        while((j<n-1)){
            int temp=a[j];
            a[j]=a[j+1];
            a[j+1]=temp;
            j++;
        }

    }
```

And could you recommend good sources to learn about time complexity and code optimization?

Comment: You do the same thing `d` times. Removing the outer loop would make it `d` times faster.

Comment: use `List` instead of `Array`. with list you can remove object on one position, and add it on other

Comment: @AndyTurner I know that, how do I do that without for or while loop is the question?

Comment: @anatoli But the problem needs to be done usingarrays. Not using lists.

Comment: One optimizaton that is definitely required is to declare the varaible's j ,temp outside of loop

Comment: @ThomasLazer - why do you think that will have any effect? Have you compared the bytecode before and after doing that?

Comment: @anatoli - Why do you think that would have any effect? Do you understand that an `ArrayList` (the only one that provides O(1) access is an object that has an underlying array?

Comment: @NithinGowda - *Andy Turner* gave you the correct answer for this example. This looks like homework or an interview question. If the latter, I suspect that you remembered the problem incorrectly. If the former, you need to copy the _exact_ problem. As written, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @NithinGowda this is just rotating an array by d positions, yes? There is a well-known solution to this, based on reversing portions of the array.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing here is left-shifting the array by d places without using allocating additional storage.

To do a left-shift by `d` places:

- Reverse the whole array (`n/2` swaps)
- Reverse the first `n-d` elements in the array (`(n-d)/2` swaps)
- Reverse the last `d` elements in the array (`d/2` swaps)

This does `n` swaps in total (and independent of `d`), so its time complexity is `O(n)`.

You can implement this like so:

```
void reverse(int[] arr, int from, int to) {
  while (from+1 < to) {
    --to;
    int tmp = arr[from];
    arr[from] = arr[to];
    arr[to] = tmp;
    ++from;
  }
}

int n = arr.length;
reverse(arr, 0, n);
reverse(arr, 0, n-d);
reverse(arr, n-d, n);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you think about it, you need to `swap d times` all elements of an `array` which has the `lenght of n elements`. This makes an `O(n*d)` which is `O(n^2)` with `d = n`. If you realy need to `swap` each element, there is no improvement in my point of view.

But if you only want the result, this code is much better:

```
public static int[] change(int[] array, int d) {
    int[] tempArray = new int[array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        int place = Math.floorMod(i - d, array.length);       //calculating the new index for array[i]
        tempArray[place] = array[i];
    }
    return tempArray;
}
```

This code has an O(n). If you know about modulo calculation, you should understand what I am doing.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that it would be simpler (albeit more opaque) to replace the loop with two calls to `System.arraycopy`: `System.arraycopy(array, d, tempArray, 0, n-d); System.arraycopy(array, n-d, tempArray, n-d, d);`, or something like that.

Comment: Thanks @AndyTurner I didn't know this because I just started learning Java. But it is very interresing.

Comment: @AndyTurner but wouldn't the second invokation need to be `System.arraycopy(array, 0, tempArray, n-d, d);`? 
First you `copyed` all elements starting from d to the end of the original array. Now we need to copy the array from `index 0` to `index d` or am I wrong?

Comment: you could well be right. I said "something like" ;)

Answer (score 1):

If what is intended in your algorithm is to shift element `d` times, then you don't really need 2 loops: you need one and only one loop.

I tested your with an array of size `100000000`, and it took 5463 seconds.

My solution, however, took 1702 ms.

Swapping actually is not necessary. Instead, using Insertion sort "technique" is better.

The proposed solution to contemplate is as the following:

```
void rotate(int d) {
    for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
        rightShift();
    }
}

void rightShift() {
    int v = a[a.length - 1];
    for (int i = a.length - 2; i >= 0 ; i --) {
        a[i + 1] = a[i];
    }
    a[0] = v;
}
```

Please note that you don't need to perform unnecessary swaps (when `d >= n`).

To solve this problem, use `d = d % n`.

Comment: If you think about it, you are still using two loops. In `rotate()` is one `for-loop` in which you are calling `rightShift()` with another `for-loop`. 
Because of this, the time complexity is still `O(n*d)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer[] temp = new Integer[d];

// store moved items in temp
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    temp[i] = a[i];
}

// replace once items in array
for (int j = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
    a[j] = a[j+d];
}

// add on end the temp items
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++) {
    a[n + i] = temp[i];
}
```

this reduce complexity by d calls